# Fetched results for a relationship

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple object graph with person and item entities. I have a one to many relationship from person to items and the inverse. I want to show in a tableview all of the items that belong to the selected person using a fetched results controller so I don't have to deal with updating the table views when I add and delete etc. How can I do this? It's driving me crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are ok with setting up and using `NSFetchedResultsController` in general or are happy to refer to the Apple sample code and documentation? So I'm guessing you are asking how to construct an `NSFetchRequest` to fetch the Item objects for a particular person which you can then pass to the fetched results controller?  If so here is an example of how it's done.

```
Person *person1 = [self someMethodThatReturnsTheRightPersonObject];
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];
// Assumes the inverse relationship Item -> Person is named "person"
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person==%@", person1];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"someKindOfOrderingAttibute" ascending:YES]];
```